# Webcam not working with Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS 64-bit

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, ubuntu-12.04, webcam

I have installed Cheese Webcam Booth from ubuntu software center but my when I run this software I am getting following message/error.

"No device found"

I also installed Camorama Webcam viewer but it also does not work and I get the following error

"Could not connect to video device(dev/video0) Please check connection. "

My laptop is Dell Inspiron 3521 which is certified for ubuntu here

But still Webcam is not working. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS 64-bit.

Do I need some drivers for Webcam? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It could be so, that you need some drivers. First, identify your webcam model and ID, by typing 'lsusb' in the terminal. Then check if your Webcam is supported by UVC (http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#devices) and try to install the latest version. Also, since you have an ID, you can just google for it.